# What is the /opt/mingw64 /opt/mingw32 equivalent for Ubuntu

Tags: cross-compilation, crossplatform, mingw32

Many manuals and tutorials about cross compiling windows binaries with the MinGW toolchain pointing out `/opt/mingw64` or `/opt/mingw32`.

E.g. like this

```
$ sudo PATH=$PATH:/opt/mingw64/bin make install
```

or here

```
CROSS_COMPILE="x86_64-w64-mingw32-" ./Configure mingw64 no-asm shared --prefix=/opt/mingw64
```

All these examples assume that the MinGW toolchain is installed by hand. What is now the equivalent if I installed the MinGW toolchain via apt?

update: To clarify this, I know my system and I know where things get installed. I ask more for the "best practice" to use them if I go the packed manager way. Think it's not the best question I ever made :)

Answer (score 1):

I just installed the packages and it looks like it installs them into `/usr` if you install using the Software Center or apt. Below is the screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you, but this is obviously.